# Problem with loading jpg images in NextJS with NGINX over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, next.js, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

For some reason when working through Nginx, jpg images are not loading. Although **svg** images work fine. Everything works via HTTP (127.0.0.1:3000), so the problem is in NGINX. I have no idea how to fix that. Im using Node v20, npm, nginx, nextjs v13.5.4

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name ylous.keenetic.link www.ylous.keenetic.link;

    server_tokens off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ylous.keenetic.link/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ylous.keenetic.link/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.ylous.keenetic.link) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        if ($host = ylous.keenetic.link) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            } # managed by Certbot


            listen 80;

            server_name ylous.keenetic.link www.ylous.keenetic.link;
            return 404; # managed by Certbot


        }
```

Next Image usage:

```
<Image src={Snicker} alt="Sniker" width={200} height={80} className="rounded-xl" priority/>
```

Example request: https://ylous.keenetic.link/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fsnicker.2ee2553c.jpg&w=640&q=75
Code: 500
Response:  "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid

All images are expected to load normally. Found someone on DigitalOcean with the **same** problem, he solved it but didn't provide the solution itself LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;        
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Everything works. I will leave the question so that other people who encounter this problem can find a solution